# Save a given string to a xml-file, but it saves the current html code of the view

Tags: xml, file, email, cakephp, opml

So, basically I have a String named `$xmlString`. It's already well-formed. I'd like to save this String temporarily into a XML-file (precisely: a [OPML](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/OPML)) and send it to a  email address.

I receive the email, it is a file with the .opml extension, but it is not filled with the content of `$xmlString`, but filled with html of the view. (you could look at it [here)](http://pastebin.com/ivcGsxJa)

This is my Controller:

```
App::uses('AppController', 'Controller');
App::uses('CakeEmail', 'Network/Email');
App::uses('File', 'Utility');

class UsersController extends AppController {
    public function beforeFilter() {
        parent::beforeFilter();
        // Set XML
        if ($this->RequestHandler->isXml()) {
            $this->RequestHandler->setContent('xml');
        }
}

  public function sendOpml($xmlString) {

    $this->autoRender=false;
    $xmlString=$this->render();

    //here is something wrong...    
    file_put_contents(TMP.'podcasts.opml', $xmlString);

    $Email = new CakeEmail('default');
    $Email->from(array('my@mailadress.com' => 'Podcaster'));
    ...
    $Email->attachments(array(
        'podcasts.opml' => array(
            'file' => TMP.'podcasts.opml',
            'mimetype' => 'text/x-opml')));
    $Email->send('My message');
  }
}
?>
```

Could somebody explain me why it is not the original string in there?

Comment: Could you explain why are you doing this `$xmlString = $this->render();`?? Seems really weird. Didn't you said the string is already well-formed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem was the random render in the action

```
  public function sendOpml($xmlString) {
     $this->autoRender=false;
     $xmlString=$this->render(); /*this is the problem */
```

Since the string was already well formatted (and anyway it's not really pretty to assign a render() to a variable), there was no need to handle it that way before putting it in a file to be attached.